# NetzpSearchAdvanced6 support of multiple sales channels?

Tags: shopware

Just installed the NetzpSearchAdvanced6 to test if it where the plugin i looked for..

I am having 2 different sales channels, and some shopping experiences hooked to one sales channel and some to the orther...

But it seems like that the plugin don't care what sales channel you are on and if it actually got access to the content i finds.

Anyone tried setting this plugin up with multiple sales channels and manage it only to find results hooked to the visited sales channel?

Answer (score 0):

If this is about https://store.shopware.com/en/netzp61864019362/advanced-search-in-blog-cms-manufacturers-and-categories.html it seems to be a paid plugin with support. In this case I suggest you to ask the vendor for support.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.